# Writing a dataset to different XML files

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My goal is to read an input file into a dataset, read data from a database into a dataset, join the dataset on account numbers, and output specified information to XML files with 50K records per file. I have a total about 2.7million.

I am able to successfully read the file, read the database, and join the two.

```
finalDSExport.repartition(1).write().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag", "root").option("rowTag","record").save("test.xml");
```

With that code I can write everything to an XML file. Is there a way to split it up to 50K records per file?

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid altering my original data structure unless I need to and it doesn't seem like you'd need to in this situation.

Why don't you just use a for loop and write to a file when every 50k iterations? You can find the number of elements in the dataset using [count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#count()).